# Convert UTC RFC3339 Timestamp to Local Time with the time crate

Tags: rust, time, timezone-offset, rfc3339

I've been banging my head against the [time](https://crates.io/crates/time) crate for the last two days. I can't find, where in their documentation how to take a RFC3339 UTC `2022-12-28T02:11:46Z` timestamp and convert that to local time for `America/New_York` (`2022-12-27T21:11:46`). I stepped away from using the `chrono` crate on advise that there is/was a vulnerability and it's not very well maintained as it once was. `Chrono` also depends on `time` but in the `0.1.x` branch of it.

My cargo.toml includes the line `time = { version = "0.3", features = ["macros", "parsing", "local-offset"] }` so enable the features I think I need.

````
use time::{format_description::well_known::Rfc3339, PrimitiveDateTime};


/// The paramater zulu would be a RFC3339 formatted string.
///
/// ```
/// #use time::{format_description::well_known::Rfc3339, PrimitiveDateTime};
/// assert_eq!("2022-12-27T21:11:46", date_time_local("2022-12-28T02:11:46Z".to_string()));
/// ```
fn date_time_local(zulu: &String) -> String {
    match PrimitiveDateTime::parse(zulu, &Rfc3339) {
        Ok(local) => local.to_string(),
        Err(..) => zulu.to_owned(),
    }
}
````

I'm having no such luck here.

Comment: By the way, the original standard is [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). RFC 3339 is but a self-declared “profile” with some poorly chosen changes that violate the original standard. I suggest sticking with ISO 8601 strictly.

Comment: *"I stepped away from using the chrono crate on advise that there is/was a vulnerability and it's not very well maintained as it once was"* - Curious about the source on this one. A year ago it was lacking maintainers, but [last release](https://crates.io/crates/chrono/versions) was a couple months ago and [commit activity](https://github.com/chronotope/chrono/commits/main) looks healthy. There are [a couple concerns](https://deps.rs/crate/chrono/0.4.23) but both have [been](https://github.com/chronotope/chrono/issues/865) [addressed](https://github.com/chronotope/chrono/issues/602).

Answer (score 0):

````
fn main() {
    assert_eq!("2022-12-27 21:11:46", date_time_local(&"2022-12-28T02:11:46Z".to_string()));
}

/// The parameter zulu should be a RFC3339 formatted string.
/// This converts that Zulu timestamp into a local timestamp.
/// ```
/// assert_eq!("2022-12-27 21:11:46", date_time_local("2022-12-28T02:11:46Z".to_string()));
/// ```
fn date_time_local(zulu: &String) -> String {
    use time::{format_description::well_known::Rfc3339, PrimitiveDateTime, UtcOffset};

    // Determine Local TimeZone
    let utc_offset = match UtcOffset::current_local_offset() {
        Ok(utc_offset) => utc_offset,
        Err(..) => return zulu.to_owned(),
    };

    // Parse the given zulu paramater.
    let zulu_parsed = match PrimitiveDateTime::parse(zulu, &Rfc3339) {
        Ok(zulu_parsed) => zulu_parsed.assume_utc(),
        Err(..) => return zulu.to_owned(),
    };

    // Convert zulu to local time offset.
    let parsed = zulu_parsed.to_offset(utc_offset);

    format!(
        "{:04}-{:02}-{:02} {:02}:{:02}:{:02}",
        parsed.year(),
        parsed.month() as u8,
        parsed.day(),
        parsed.hour(),
        parsed.minute(),
        parsed.second()
    )
}
````

With a slight change that I removed the `T` between the date and the time.